# Sending keys / manipulating value of input field (vue.JS input)

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to send data to an input field on this website: https://www.avigilon.com/how-to-buy/partner-locator

You can programmatically identify the input using the following:

```
let input = $('input[placeholder="Zip code / Postal code"]')[0]
```

if you then pass `input.value = '33701'` it will change the input, but the moment you press 'Search' it resets it to the null value.

I typed a few keys in, then changed it using `input.value = '33701'` and it reset it back to the keys i'd typed in manually, so I tried passing a keyup event like this: `input.dispatchEvent(new KeyboardEvent('keyup', {'key': '3'}));` but it didnt add the key. I added an event listener and the event is triggering, but the key is just not being added to the input.

I tried this same event dispatch method in my own app and it accepted the key. I also tried `keydown` and `keypress`.

I looked at the page source and noticed the input field has a property called `v-model='selectedZipcode'`. I've never used Vue before so I didn't recognize it. In doing research, it looks like the v-model input components accept keys differently to regular inputs.

I am struggling to find info on how I can pass keys into this v-model input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't even need to set the zipcode, just reference the Vue app itself and call:

```js
app.getLocationFromZip(33701)
```

Comment: Thanks, this works! If you don't mind me asking, why does it work / how did you figure it out?

Comment: I just inspected the code and saw that it was using a Vue app. Took a guess on the referenced `parter-locator-vue.js` script, opened it up, and saw the obvious `getLocationFromZip` function. Shame on them for not compressing and minifying their JS code.